# pageViewController viewControllerAfter/Before dataSource methods called twice

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I want to show some data in a pager-like way, so I thought using `UIPageViewController, and this is basically what I have done:

```
struct ModelTest {
    var number: Int
}


class PagerViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var currentIndex = 0

    var models: [ModelTest] = [
        ModelTest(number: 1),
        ModelTest(number: 2),
        ModelTest(number: 3),
        ModelTest(number: 4),
        ModelTest(number: 5)
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        if let firstModel = models.first {
            setViewControllers([ModelViewController(firstModel)], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let nextIndex = currentIndex + 1
        guard nextIndex < models.count else {
            return nil
        }
        self.currentIndex += 1
        return ModelViewController(models[nextIndex])
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let previousIndex = currentIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return nil
        }
        self.currentIndex -= 1
        return ModelViewController(models[previousIndex])
    }

}
```

However, for some reason the `dataSource` methods `viewControllerAfter` and `viewControllerBefore` sometimes get called twice. Do you have any idea of why and how to solve this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think its datasource also assing in your storyboard layout of pageviewcontroller so remove from there or remove from viewdidLoad

Answer (score 0):

As you are subclassing 'UIPageViewController' not 'UIViewController', no need to set delegate again.

Remove below line and it should work fine.

> self.dataSource = self